# ReactJS Update ajax call to child component from onClick method from parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs

I have an array of data being passed from one json file.

When I click on the list item it triggers a `handleClick` method that will get the new url and set it to the provided state. That state is then passed onto a child component that makes an ajax call using that link.

The problem is that the ajax call only loads once when the component is mounted and does not make anymore calls after that no matter how many times I click on it.

How would I get the child component to load a new url each time a different item is clicked?

Parent Component:

```
getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        gameUrl: ''
    };
},
handleClick: function() {
    this.setState({
        gameUrl: gameUrl
    });
},
render: function() {
    var gameList = this.props.data.map(function(game) {
        var homeTeamName = game.home_team_name;
        var awayTeamName = game.away_team_name;

        var gameUrl = game.game_directory+'/anotherFile.json';
        console.log(homeTeamName+' vs '+awayTeamName+':'+ gameUrl);

        var click = this.handleClick;
        return (
            <li key={game.location} className="list-group-item" onClick={click}>
               {homeTeamName}
            </li>   
        );
    }, bind);
    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                {gameList}
            </ul>
            <GameDetail url={this.state.gameUrl}/>
        </div>
    );
```

Child Component:

```
    componentDidMount: function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({
            data: data.data
        });
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
},
```

Comment: Making an ajax call from a child component is a code smell, IMO.

Comment: @Mathletics I too don't believe this is the best practice but, I am not sure of how else to go about it. I have a list view that is generated through an ajax call. Then within each list contains another link to that specific lists data. Is there another way I could pull that data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @WitVault managed to do it here is the revised section:

Instead of componentDidMount, I changed it to componentWillReceiveProps in the child component. Make sure the prop you're passing through is the same in the child and parent component. (i.e. in child component the prop is `url`, in the parent you're passing it to the same prop `<GameDetail url={this.state.gameUrl}/>`) Then you access it in the `componentWillReceiveProps` method via `nextProps.url`

```
componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {
// Access the url prop
var newUrl = nextProps.url;
$.ajax({
  url: newUrl,
  dataType: 'json',
  cache: false,
  success: function(data) {
    this.setState({
        data: data.data
    });
  }.bind(this),
  error: function(xhr, status, err) {
    console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
  }.bind(this)
});
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement `componentWillReceiveProps` method.
It will be called when the props have changed and when this is not an initial rendering.Then update the state depending on the existing and upcoming props.

```
componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {
  this.setState({
    // set something 
  });
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the noobie question but, do I put this in the child or parent component? If in the child, how will it know the props have changed (more specifically the `url` prop?

Comment: @Simon You have to put it in child component. Next prop received in `componentWillReceiveProps`  will contain the changed url. You can access it in the same as you were doing it previously.